# faster javascript loader pixel count

Tags: javascript, image-processing

I was trying to simulate canvas with only div tags with 1 pixel each - so i set divs in nodes, and it make me fill sad! Why we have 2.073.600 pixels controled by computer all the time and if we set it to div control its eats too much memory and be so slow? Its just a full hd page...

function loadskecth(){

```
var totalblocksX = 1920
var totalblocksY = 1080

        for(var addedblocksY = 0 ; addedblocksY < totalblocksY; addedblocksY++){

            let blocklineY = document.createElement("article");
                blocklineY.style.display        = "flex"
                blocklineY.style.flexDirection  = "row"

                for(var addedblocksX = 0 ; addedblocksX < totalblocksX; addedblocksX++){
                    
                    let blocklineX = document.createElement("article");
                    
                    let block     = document.createElement("div")
                        block.style.backgroundColor = "black"
                        block.style.height       = "1px"
                        block.style.width        = "1px"

                        block.onmouseover        = function(){block.style.backgroundColor = "orange"}

                        blocklineX.append(block)
                        blocklineY.append(blocklineX)
                }
                addedblocksX = 0
        scketch.append(blocklineY)
        }
    
    document.body.append(scketch)
}
```

loadskecth()

var blocksizeX = 200
var blocksizeY = 200

var blocklineX = 200
var blocklineY = 200

var addedblocksY = 0

document.body.style.margin = "0px"

any ideas to be more fast? any questions?

Comment: Yep, that'll happen... interacting with the DOM is slow. Adding millions of elements to the DOM will take ages. Images (`<img>` or `<canvas>`) are much more efficient.

Comment: well, but whats the difference between image canvas and dom speeds?

Comment: A canvas is far, far faster.

Comment: The canvas is hardware-accelerated which allows it to be much more efficient both in memory and speed.

Comment: @carlos Canvas is “just pixels” laid out in a grid. Think of a photo image or paint program. In the case of the DOM ‘pixels’, each element takes up significantly more resources to represent, layout, and render. For 40k elements (200 x 200), this is already *a lot of work* and it’s a *squared problem* 1680 x 1024 = **1.7 million**.

Comment: Anyway, assuming even an vary basic DOM model, each one of these elements might take up *very minimally* 80+ bytes for basic information and layout (reference, type, position, applied style). And this is likely a significant undercount that doesn’t even consider layout computing memory and CPU costs. Whereas in a canvas each pixel is only 4 bytes of information and requires effectively no computation to “move” to the screen.

Comment: That said, if continuing with this “DOM pixel” approach, I might consider using absolute positioning and styles applied (position:absolute, width, height, top, background) and *inherited via CSS selector* in a parent container row (with a width and height explicitly applied to the row itself). Then each element would specify its own left as an inline style. This might help reduce memory and layout costs. YMMV.